# Declaration of isspace in C/C++ not consistent?

Tags: c++, c, clang, std, header-files

I believe there must have been discussions about it, but I just cannot understand why `isspace` is not consistent for C and C++

(I am using **clang** analyzer to get the definition information)

```
// test.c
#include <ctype.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  isspace('a');
  return 0;
}
```

clang reports below as the declaration of isspace:

```
# define isspace(c) __isctype((c), _ISspace)  // LINE 207 in /usr/include/ctype.h
```

and when for this snippet:

```
// test.cpp
#include <cctype>
int main() {
  std::isspace('t');
  return 0;
}
```

clang reports the declaration here:

```
__exctype (isspace);  // LINE 120 in /usr/include/ctype.h
// #define  __exctype(name) extern int name (int) __THROW
```

So why should there be such a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as it *behaves* consistently, that's all the C and C++ standards require.

In C, the standard defines `isspace` as a library function. Like any standard library function, an implementation is permitted, but not required, to define it additionally as a macro -- as long as the macro does the same thing as the function. If it's defined as a macro, you can always bypass it to access the function:

```
(isspace)(c) /* the parentheses around the name inhibit macro expansion */
```

or

```
#undef isspace
isspace(c);
```

But unless you need a pointer to the function, there's rarely any reason to do this.

In C++, macros aren't affected by namespaces, so `std::isspace` can't refer to a macro. Depending on the implementation, it probably refers to the same function that `isspace` refers to in C. You can still refer to the macro by using `#include <ctype.h>` and not using the `std::` prefix.

But there's no good reason to do so. `isspace` tells you whether its argument is a whitespace character, which is what it's required to do.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But I still cannot make clang believe I am using the macro version by including `ctype.h` and removing `std::`(I also check the binary and it contains `isspace` symbol)

Comment: I just would like to ensure it, which may be not significant in real usage.

Comment: Maybe I should specify `-std` to make the isspace the functional one in C++ code?

Comment: @HongxuChen: No. In C, the ISO standard specifically permits, but does not require `isspace` to be implemented as a macro. In C++, since macros aren't in namespaces, `std::isspace` can't be a macro. But *it doesn't matter*; `isspace` works as defined whether it's a macro or not. Why do you care?

Comment: I am doing some experiments through llvm analysis and hope C or C++ can generate the same(not exactly, I only care about the function name, regardless of the C++ mangling). So I hope `isspace` and the like can be represented consistently in the binary file(actually in llvm IR). Since it might difficulty to use the macro definition for C++, I would switch to use `(isspace)(c)` form for C code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

C++ has a function `template< class CHAR > bool isspace( CHAR, const std::locale& );` which would break horribly if `isspace` is in fact a macro. Historically, in C it was a macro for performance reasons.

Comment: Since the 1989 ANSI C standard, `isspace` is defined as a function. Like any standard library function an implementation is permitted, but not required, to additionally define it as a macro, presumably for performance reasons. I don't think there's ever been a *requirement* that to define `isspace` as a macro.

Comment: True. In this case we see that `clang` uses a macro in C mode, and I explained why that can't work in C++.

Answer (score 0):

What difference are you talking about? Those are just two different names for the same function.

> **C Language Library**
>
> The C++ library includes the same definitions as
>   the C language library organized in the same structure of header
>   files, with the following differences:
>
> - Each header file has the same
>     name as the C language version but with a "c" prefix and no extension.
>     For example, the C++ equivalent for the C language header file
>     `<stdlib.h>` is `<cstdlib>`.
> - Every element of the library is defined
>     within the `std` namespace.

*(from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/))*

---

OK, if you look around those lines in `ctype.h` you've mentioned, you'll notice that line 120 declares this function. And its implementation is given on line 207.

You shouldn't care about it all. Really.

Comment: But seems not true for this case! the declaration of `isspace` is **different** for C and C++ code.

Comment: @HongxuChen Waht makes you think so? What I am seeing is that it is `int isspace( int ch )` in both cases.

Comment: I don't know, but the analyzer tells so. I just cannot understand.

Comment: @HongxuChen I've updated my answer. The real question is: why would you ever care about it?

Comment: I don't believe that `__isctype_f (space)` is used since according to the analyzer `__isctype_f` is not defined.

Comment: @HongxuChen Probably. It depends on a number of factors. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I just would like to know why there should be inconsistency.

Comment: @HongxuChen Well, OK, I don't think I'm competent enough to answer this question. I think you should ask it on the glibc mailing list.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Would you please add the link as well? Thanks. I am lost in finding that.

Comment: @HongxuChen By the way, I've just noticed that `__isctype` and `__isctype_f` are doing exactly the same thing. The difference is that the latter declares functions, while the former is just a macro. Nevertheless it seems to me that there are codepaths leading to both macros not being defined. I guess in this case actual implementations are linked from somewhere else.

Comment: It seems so from the src(although I cannot fully understand it).